# laravel 5.4 cannot run the following php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel

laravel 5.4 cannot run the following

php artisan migrate

because there was Base table or view already exists

how to solve this problem ???

Answer (score 1):

It shows in which table is the problem ?

Try to run `php artisan migrate:reset` and then check for your forign keys and try to migrate again

Answer (score 0):

If you modified the schema after running migrate, but didn't create a new migration file for the schema changes you can no longer migrate until you drop the 'migrations' table.

For development, this is a pain.  So I've created an artisan command to just drop the whole database and recreate it.

[DBClear.php](https://gist.github.com/fastmover/bd586498c038fc65a158b600bd5e61df)

Copy this gist file into your app/Console/Commands folder, then add it to the app/Console/Kernel.php.

```
protected $commands = [

    Commands\DBClear::class,

];
```